# JS/CSS/Bootstrap - styling selected button from button group

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a basic button group like so:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="responses" value="1">
    Poor
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="responses" value="2">
    Average
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="responses" value="3">
    Good
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="responses" value="4">
    Very good
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="5" name="responses" value="5">
    Excellent
  </label>
</div>
```

And I want to be able to change the background color of the checked option.

I cannot figure out how to select this in CSS. I am aiming for either a JS or CSS solution.

Answer (score 1):

the idea is to capture the `input` event on `input` element and apply a styling class to it's parent `label`, like so:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('input', e => {
    document.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(l => {
      l.classList.remove('checked');
    });
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('checked');
  });
});
```

```css
label.checked {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="1" name="responses" value="1">
    Poor
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="2" name="responses" value="2">
    Average
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="3" name="responses" value="3">
    Good
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="4" name="responses" value="4">
    Very good
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" id="5" name="responses" value="5">
    Excellent
  </label>
</div>
```